# My JS only my first event is firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason only my first event is firing.  If I change the order of the events, only the first one still get's fired.

```
<input type="numeric" name="zip" id="zip" maxlength="5" size="5" min="0" max="99999">
<button type="button" name="zipbutton" id="zipbutton">Search!</button>
<br>

<select name="milesdropdown" id="milesdropdown" >
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10" selected>10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

Here is the JS:

```
        $('#milesdropdown').change(function () {
            alert("miles changed");
        });

        $('#zipbutton').onclick(function () {
            alert("button clicked");
        });
```

If I change the order, then still only the first one get's picked up!

Comment: Look at the error in the console.

Comment: ...and when you do, you'll notice something very peculiar about this `onclick` function you want to call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery does not have an `onclick()` function. To add a handler to the click event, call [`click()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=click).

You could also use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) function:

```
$('#milesdropdown').on('change', function () {
    alert("miles changed");
});

$('#zipbutton').on('click', function () {
    alert("button clicked");
});
```

Comment: Or, preferably, `$(element).on('click', function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function() {
      $('#milesdropdown').change(function () {
            alert("miles changed");
        });

        $('#zipbutton').click(function () {
            alert("button clicked");
        });
  });
```

Did you tried like this?

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is a native function of Javascript.
You can override this function by your own like this (stupid example, just for explain this method) :

```
$('#zipbutton')[0].onclick = function () {
 alert("button clicked");
};
// $('#zipbutton')[0] = document.getElementById('zipbutton')
```

Comment: You are mixing jQuery with native js, this is a bad practice.

Comment: Your example is good, but can be wrong interpreted. I have cancelled my down vote :)